# ASP.NET Eval() a Key generated by a GroupBy()

Tags: asp.net, linq, group-by, key, eval

I have the following piece of linq:

```
            var r = db.tblCommonSalesDrivers.Join(db.tblScenarioQuarters, c => c.tblScenarioQuarter, s => s, (csd, sq) => new { Csd = csd, Sq = sq })
                                .GroupBy(c => c.Csd.tblParameter)
                                .GroupBy(c => c.Key.tblParameterGroup);
```

This gives me a group of tblParameterGroup each of which contain a group of tblParameter which in turn contain a group of the anonymous type.

I want to bind it to a Repeter and Eval one of the properties in the tblParameterGroup like this:

```
<%# Eval("Key.SomeProperty") %>
```

When I do this, the control can't see the Key but it is there in the Watch window.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataRepeater can't use tblPatameterGroup at that deep of a level.  You will need to use .SelectMany on your current result to get to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but tblPatameterGroup is at the very top of the hierarchy, my idea is to use three nested repeaters to display all information in the structure. If I used SelectMany I don't believe I would be able to do this, would I?